# event.target not giving desired output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is

```
<div id="hello">
<div>A</div></div>
<script>
$(function(){
$(document).mousedown(function(event){alert(event.target.id);});
});</script>
```

Now when i click on div id "hello" it is alerting null as it is taking the id of center div but i want the id of outer div.How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why do you think that clicking on 'A' will output its parent's id? Or clicking elsewhere, will output #hello's id ?

Comment: event capturing and bubbling. Take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the target was the innermost div

[try this instead](http://jsfiddle.net/fPtSS/):

```
event.target.parentNode.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code slightly:

```
<div id="hello">
<div>A</div></div>
<script>

$(function(){
    //You can change the selector to what suits you best here
    $("body>div").mousedown(function(event){alert(event.currentTarget.id);});

    //it is safer to use currentTarget when you have nested elements
});</script>
```

Comment: It's just your code slightly changed. In your code you are attaching the event listeners to any div, but your intention is to attach it only to the div(s) with ids - in your case it is the child of 'body' but it may vary depending on your final code...

Comment: And if you put an ID on the inner div and change the selector to `"body>div,body>div>div"` you get two alerts.  Seems like that or the event.target.parentNode.id with the "document" selector would work.

Comment: Of course, if you change the selector to something like this `"body>div,body>div>div"` you will be adding the listener twice, hence two alerts. No surprise there.

Answer (score 0):

use `event.target.parentNode.id`

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the event to the div you are interested in. In your case, you should bind it to `$('#hello')`

If you have multiple divs you want to have that event binded, add a class to them, and bind the mousedown event to that class, and in your callback function check the event.target's id.